# PayPal API response for an action doesn't contains status code or any other boolean value

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, cfml

I want to perform an action on the basis of payment success, but the response does not contain any boolean value

Comment: There are various possible integration methods and associated APIs; you'll have to provide more detail about your exact implementation -- and a log of the exact response you are getting on payment completion

Comment: Please be more specific. It is not clear what the problem is. What request and response are you talking about?

Comment: @ooorndtski 
 i am sending HTTP call using <cfhttp> to paypal payment api.
payment state is approved means it is going successful.
Problem is that response from the api do not contains ' Status Code OK ' OR anyother boolean value 'yes/no' OR  'true/false' 
while i need a boolean value from the response so that i can execute a piece of code  enclosed in <cfif> on the bases of response whether it is going successfull or not .